monitor is unknown
I installed a additional touchscreen to my laptop over displaylink.
The screen itself works fine. But the vendor / model / serialno is set to "unknown".
I need these value to map the touchscreen to the monitor.
How can I name the display correct?
EDID seems to be correct.
hwinfo --monitor shows correct data.
.config/monitor.xml is unknown.
I'm running Fedora 40 / gnome 46 / wayland
